# PHP APC DLL for xampp 1.8.1

Tags: php, xampp, apc

Where can i find the matching php apc dll for xampp 1.8.1 on windows xp sp3 32 bit, PHP Version 5.4.7 and Zend Extension Build-API220100525,TS,VC9 ?

Answer (score 9):

I found working apc.dll Here: 
http://belsky.info/uploads/my/bugz/61984/php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86-xp.zip[1](http://belsky.info/uploads/my/bugz/61984/php_apc-3.1.10-5.4-vc9-x86-xp.zip)

Comment: This worked for me (XAMPP 1.8.1 on Windows 7 64-bit). Beware that there are 2 php_apc.dll files in there. Try them both.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the php_apc.dll from this site:
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/apc/

Answer (score 0):

You can download APC application from  http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Comment: given links shows "You don't have permission to access /~pierre/ on this server."